Word prints large white margins (left and bottom)
For some reason, my A4 sized printouts that are supposed to have standard 1" margins, come out scaled smaller and moved to the top right of the printed A4 sheet.
The printer involved is a Brother DCP-L3510CDW which has been operating properly for several years. The laptop used (Win10) is about half a year old and until maybe a month ago did not have this issue. The Brother iPrint & Scan software is fully updated (12.0.3.2).
The current workaround is creating a PDF (which always prints as intended). I therefore suspect there's an unusual problem with my word documents themselves.
How do I get rid of this behaviour?
This is a scanned printout (black rim line added for contrast):

And this is the print preview preceding it, you can see the spacing around the text was supposed to be even:

The associated page setup:
 

And finally the associated printer properties:


The source here is a docx test document in which I pasted unformatted lorem ipsum text (and gave the first line a title formatting).
I have not modified any of these settings, other than the number of pages per sheet, page orientation and duplex orientation in the printer properties.
This behaviour only happens on my home printer (on a domain printer that I've also been using frequently, the same document comes out fine). It also appears to differ between documents, old docs seem to always come out normal whereas most docx'es produce this problem.

Letter and A4 are close enough in size that this mix up (that happens frequently) doesn't have significant scaling issues. Something we unfortunately have to live with, letter frequently being set as the default format for printers, even though A4 is the default paper size here. I did try this to rule it out, unfortunately with the same strongly scaled printout...

Printer driver should be up to date, might give a reinstall a try. 'storing A5 as scalar' sounds interesting, the printed area does seem like an A5. How could this possibly happen, and more importantly, where do I change this?

Does it only happen in that document? If not, does it only happen in Word? or also in Notepad? If it seems to be happening everywhere, it might be that the margin is actually set in the printer settings or driver, rather than the word processor.

Also, why do your advanced printer settings say Letter and the basic one says A4?
